# Syntax error with uiSelect2

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I'm trying to use string concatenation in a `ng-repeat` in a `ui-select2`:

```
    <select ui-select2 ng-model="selected2" style="width:300px;">
        <option ng-repeat="item in data[it + 'ems']" selected 
                value="{{item}}">{{item}}</option>
    </select>
```

(This is a trivial example, but the string concatenation is necessary for code reuse.)

It works just fine on a normal `select`. However, `uiSelect2` produces an error:

```
Error: Syntax Error: Token ']' is an unexpected token at column 6 of the expression ['ems']] starting at []].
    at Error (<anonymous>)
    at throwError (http://code.angularjs.org/angular-1.0.1.js:5830:11)
    at parser (http://code.angularjs.org/angular-1.0.1.js:5824:5)
    at http://code.angularjs.org/angular-1.0.1.js:6387:29
    at compileToFn (http://code.angularjs.org/angular-1.0.1.js:8040:16)
    at Object.Scope.$watch (http://code.angularjs.org/angular-1.0.1.js:7547:19)
    at http://angular-ui.github.com/angular-ui/build/angular-ui.js:911:19
    at nodeLinkFn (http://code.angularjs.org/angular-1.0.1.js:4223:13)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://code.angularjs.org/angular-1.0.1.js:3838:14)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://code.angularjs.org/angular-1.0.1.js:3841:12) <select ui-select2="" ng-model="selected2" style="width:300px;" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
```

Reproduced in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/_nth/6Zjd9/1/).

Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect it's because select-ui has an isolated scope, and so does ng-repeat, which puts your `it` variable out of reach of that ng-repeat.

I recommend using [ng-options](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3aselect) for selects anyhow.. (which works, presumably because it prevents the scoping issue I mentioned):

```
<select ui-select2 ng-model="selected2" style="width:300px;" 
  ng-options="item for item in data[it + 'ems']"></select>
```

Comment: That is a good point. However, I need it to be an `ng-repeat` so I have access to `$first`, `$last`, and `$index`. Is there any way I can make it work that way?

Comment: If you need access to those, you can always play with accessing properties on the scope "above" your `ng-repeat` using `$parent`. so like  `{{$parent.it}}` or whatever. Just be careful, it's really easy to turn your code into something hard to maintain if you start using `$parent` too often.

Comment: But why would the string concatenation affect whether or not `it` is in scope?

Comment: The string concatenation doesn't effect it. It's the fact that you're trying to access `it` from within the ng-repeat's scope, and not the scope `it` was defined in. If that makes sense.

Comment: But when I access `it` by itself, without string concatenation, it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/_nth/6Zjd9/2/

Comment: Looking at all of those errors in the console log, I'm starting to think it's more of a bug within that ui-select2 directive.

Comment: I was considering filing a bug with ui-select2, but I wanted to be sure I wasn't doing something dumb before doing so.